# How to parse with xml.etree? Python

Tags: python, parsing

Python 3.5

See the code

```
import urllib.request
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

url = 'http://www.sat.gob.mx/informacion_fiscal/tablas_indicadores/Paginas/tipo_cambio.aspx'


def conectar(url):
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return page.read()

root = ET.fromstring(conectar(url))
s = root.findall("//*[contains(.,'21/')]")
```

A need extract `'21/'`, but return this error:

```
Erro:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawler.py", line 11, in <module>
    root = ET.fromstring(conectar(url))
  File "/home/rg3915/.pyenv/versions/3.5.0/lib/python3.5/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1321, in XML
    parser.feed(text)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: unbound prefix: line 146, column 8
```

But I do not know how to solve this error.

Comment: Why not using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: As it would be in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.sat.gob.mx/informacion_fiscal/tablas_indicadores/Paginas/tipo_cambio.aspx'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
dom = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

tables = dom.find_all("table")
if len(tables):
    table = tables[0]
    print table
```

(tested in python 2.7)

Answer (score 1):

While the document you are trying to parse claims to be xhtml, it is invalid xml due to the unbound prefix.

```
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

The `gcse` ns prefix is not defined for the document.

[BeautifulSoup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) would probably be much better suited for what you are trying to do, because it is not fussy about the document being 100% valid.